# How to get lists of latitude longitude with distance within specified radius from my location in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am new in Asp.Net REST Web Service development.

I am working on Asp.Net REST Web Service application which is using c# and MY SQL as database. I want to have a list of locations within specified radius(ex. 5km) from a specified location(ex. my location). I do have a list of latitude and longitude stored in a table of database. I want to have one method in service which finds out the list of lat long within specified radius(ex. 5km) from my location(another specified latitude longitude).

As this is the Web service, so I think the code must be written in c#.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on the number of entries in your database, you might want to use [Spatial Datatypes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html). These Extensions are highly optimized for queries like these and will always be faster than anything you can cook up on your client.

Comment: How many locations are there in total? For a non-trivial number of locations, you might need something a bit cleverer than a brute-force search over all locations.

Comment: @spender there are many locations in a list. Input parameter is the end-user's location and on the basis of his/her location there is a specified radius(ex. 5km/10km), for which i need to get all the latitude longitudes which are inside the circle.